# EJB Basic question

Tags: ejb

I am new to EJB and I am going thro "Enterprise Java Beans 3.1" (O'Reilly) book. In that it has been mentioned different terminologies like

EJB  ,  Bean, Remote,    Local  ,   RemoteHome,      LocalHome  ,        RemoteBusiness,        LocalBusiness

Can anybody explain what are these terminologies mean in a java-layman tone.... 
Also if you can give some details about how exactly EJB fits in an Enterprise appln. with an real-life-example-app would be great

Thanks
Shiv

Comment: You need to accept more answers for anybody to want to help you.

Comment: I dont understand Kal what you are trying to say

Comment: You have asked other questions on Stackoverflow. Go to your user page http://stackoverflow.com/users/145786/siva , click on those questions and accept ( by clicking on the check sign ) the answer that helped you the most. People spend a lot of time trying to help others on here -- you should acknowledge that.

Comment: Done that.. thanks for pointing Kal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using some books, able to infer the terms